# How to apply patches from GitHub

Tags: android, git, github

I'm building Paranoid Android, and I need to apply patches from my device tree (p8000).

Here is the link: https://github.com/visi0nary/android_device_elephone_p8000/tree/cm-12.1/patches

I see that it has .sh file, but I really dont know how to apply it. I have the sources from PA and my device tree already synced. Now all i need to do is apply this patches to make the FingerPrint sensor work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run the `.sh`(`./apply-patch` in terminal) file in a correct directory. If you run the file, directly in `patches` folder, there's already `cd` command to set correct paths for patches to apply. If this won't help, or you need to apply only some of the patches, you can apply them one-by-one with:

```
git apply -v <path to .patch file>
```